# how to identify any phone number's Country

Tags: python, java

I want to predict and create a new column named Proposed_Telephone_Country based on the phone number.

Note:- Phone number may or may not start with ISO code/ Country code. We dont know which phone number belongs to which country, hence if it matches to multiple countries i would need the top 5 matches to be populated in the country column.

I have tried using phone numbers library- geocoder and phone-iso 3166 library in python but it only predict numbers where the initials represents country code/iso code. For ex.. +61406034*** will show AU but 0406034*** (local format) will show nothing.

ALSO NOTE:- If you can suggest how to predict if number is from a list of specific country or not(10 specific countries I have). That would be of great help too.

Comment: See [ask]. This is impossible technically. And ```automation``` means automating an application simulating user inputs such as keyboard and mouse events. Remove that tag.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @relent95 I have updated the tags. And good to know that it’s impossible from your knowledge. 

I will wait to see if anyone else can suggest any solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to reliably identify the country for a phone number if the number doesn't include the standard country code prefix.  Numbers (as dialed) are only unambiguous when you know *where* they were dialed.

Therefore you won't find library that can do this (reliably).

Note that someone suggested this library:

- https://pypi.org/project/phonenumbers/

However, if you read the documentation carefully, you will see that if the number doesn't have a `+nnn` international prefix, you need to give a 2nd parameter representing a country in which to (attempt to) understand the number.  Unless you know *that*, the library doesn't have the context for interpreting the number, and hence to work out the (real) country of the number.

---

The solution to your problem will be to require the user to enter the phone number with a proper international prefix, OR enter the country explicitly as a separate field.